# Injecting an entity manager in a SFSB with Seam

Tags: transactions, dependency-injection, entity, seam, ejb

I'm building a web app using Seam, using stateful session EJBs as business components (also annotated as Seam components). In this scenario what's the best practice for injecting the entity manager, using @In or @PersistenceContext? will one of the two options cause me problems? (assume the duration of a conversation and its associated persistence context is not an issue)

If I choose to use @In and need to mark a method as non-transactional, should I use @Transactional(TransactionPropagationType.SUPPORTS) or @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to have any issue using Seam managed persistence context instead of the standard container managed persistence context, so in my opinion the best practice is using `@In`.
Among the advantages of using a Seam managed persistence context there are:

- You can inject the same persistence context in non-EJB Seam component
- Use of `<s:convertEntity>` in the view (assuming you are going to use JSF)
- Use of EL in the Query Language
- You have the persistence context bound to the conversation context (not important for you, if understand correct)

If you choose `@In`, thus Seam managed persistence context, then you can have declarative transaction demarcation using `@Transactional` in non-EJB Seam component where `@TransactionAttribute` make no sense.
For EJB session bean annotated as Seam component (`@Name`) `@TransactionAttribute` should be used with the same semantic as defined for EJB3.

Since `@Transactional` doesn't have a `REQUIRES_NEW` value the following applies as explained in the reference documentation:

*If you are using EJB3 and mark your class or method `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`
then the transaction and persistence context shouldn't be propagated to method calls on this
object. However as the Seam-managed persistence context is propagated to any component
within the conversation, it will be propagated to methods marked `REQUIRES_NEW`. Therefore,
if you mark a method `REQUIRES_NEW` then you should access the entity manager using
`@PersistenceContext`.*

Chapter 9 of Dan Allen book Seam In Action will satisfy any doubt on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll be injecting the persistence context with `@In`. However, I found some additional information that contradicts this part: "`@TransactionAttribute` has no effect on the Seam managed transaction." According to Seam's [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/persistence/3.0.0.Alpha1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e135), "If you are in an EE environment then you should always use the EJB API's, namely `@TransactionAttribute` and `@ApplicationException`."

Comment: Also, from the book "Seam Framework Experience the Evolution of Java EE", 2nd Ed., page 163: "Do not use the `@Transactional` annotation with EJB3 session beans, use the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation instead."

Comment: You are right, Oscar. I edited the response for the benefit of other users who came on this page. Thanks.